# Why do tris appear in quad faces?

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]

I have this error when I try to make retopolgy with SpeedRetopo add-on.

Comment: GPUs only render triangles, all polygons (tris, quands or NGons) are assentially made of triangles and as such forcefully converted to tris before rendering regardless of topology

Comment: Those triangles are the result of non planar faces or issues with normals.

Comment: And can I fix it?